# Ошибка при free() структуры - C

Tags: c, struct, free

```
struct SBook{
    unsigned long long ISBN; 
    char Writer[200]; 
    char Title[200]; 
    int Whole;
    int Taken;
};


void B_delete(struct SBook **Books, int *Num){ //Num - кол-во структур
    struct SBook *OldBooks = *Books;

    // спрашиваем у пользователя ввод, получаем "int find"

    *Num-=1;
    struct SBook *NewBooks = (struct SBook*) calloc(*Num - 1, sizeof(struct SBook));

    for(int i=0; i<find; i++){
        NewBooks[i].ISBN = OldBooks[i].ISBN;
        strcpy(NewBooks[i].Writer, OldBooks[i].Writer);
        strcpy(NewBooks[i].Title, OldBooks[i].Title);
        NewBooks[i].Whole = OldBooks[i].Whole;
        NewBooks[i].Taken = OldBooks[i].Taken;
    }

    for(int i=find; i<*Num; i++){
        NewBooks[i].ISBN = OldBooks[i+1].ISBN;
        strcpy(NewBooks[i].Writer, OldBooks[i+1].Writer);
        strcpy(NewBooks[i].Title, OldBooks[i+1].Title);
        NewBooks[i].Whole = OldBooks[i+1].Whole;
        NewBooks[i].Taken = OldBooks[i+1].Taken;
    }
    *Books = NewBooks;
    free(OldBooks);
    free(TakenBooks);
}
```

на `free(OldBooks);` код завершается, vs пишет: проект.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова. В чем проблема? Не понимаю, все посмотрел, все должно быть правильно

Comment: У вас TakenBooks не определено.

Comment: не, просто забыл написать, что он тож присутствует. ```struct STakenBook *TakenBooks = GetTakenBook(&Num2);```. В функции GetTakenBook() есть проверка на NULL

Comment: В данной функции я ищу структуру, которую надо удалить. Переменная find отвечает за "ту самую" структуру. Т е надо удалить 3 номер (из 20), find = 2. Find не может быть больше *Num-1

Comment: Вы же не выделили память под OldBooks. Вам не зачем её очищать, т.к. вы освободите память, на которую указывает *Books в начале функции.

Comment: А как мне очистить то, что мне приходило в *Books и потом заполнить его *NewBooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выделяете память мало. Второй раз минус один не нужно.

```
*Num-=1;
//struct SBook *NewBooks = (struct SBook*) calloc(*Num - 1, sizeof(struct SBook));
struct SBook *NewBooks = (struct SBook*) calloc(*Num , sizeof(struct SBook));
```

При порче памяти происходит неопределённое поведение и ошибки могут быть очень разными.

Comment: Спасибо, дело было в нем. Фига я гений вышмата

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код не имеет смысла, т. к. новый массив меньше старого, т. е. можно использовать его повторно. Если вы хотите массив с non-fixed-size (называется список), то он бы выглядел вот так:

```c
typedef char* SBinary;
typedef unsigned long SSize;
typedef char SBoolean;

#ifndef TRUE
#   define TRUE ((SBoolean)1)
#endif
#ifndef FALSE
#   define FALSE ((SBoolean)0)
#endif

typedef struct List {
    SBinary Data;
    SSize Count;
    SSize Capacity;
    SSize ItemSize;
} SList;
typedef struct Index {
    SSize Offset;
    SBoolean IsFromEnd;
} SIndex;
```

```c
inline SSize GetIndexOffset(const SIndex Index, const SSize Length) {
    if (Index->Offset >= Length) { /*error handling*/ }

    return Index->IsFromEnd ? Length - Index->Offset : Index->Offset;
}
```

```c
void InitList(SList* List, const SBinary Data, const SSize InitialCapacity, const SSize ItemSize) {
    List->Data = Data;
    List->Count = 0;
    List->Capacity = InitialCapacity;
    List->ItemSize = ItemSize;
}
void _InitList(SList* List, const SSize InitialCapacity, const SSize ItemSize) {
    InitList(List, malloc(InitialCapacity * ItemSize), InitialCapacity, ItemSize);
}
SBoolean EnsureCapacity(SList* List, const SSize additionalCapacity) {
    SSize NewCapacity = List->Count + additionalCapacity;

    if (NewCapacity < 8U)
        NewCapacity = 8U;
    else if (NewCapacity & (NewCapacity - 1U) != 0) { // если не является степенью 2-ки
        SSize i;

        for (i = 1; i < NewCapacity; i <<= 1) { }

        NewCapacity = i;
    }

    if (List->Count + additionalCapacity <= List->Capacity) return FALSE;

    SBinary NewData = malloc(NewCapacity);
    memcpy(NewData, List->Data, List->Capacity * List->ItemSize);

    free(List->Data);

    InitList(List, NewData, NewCapacity, List->ItemSize);

    return TRUE;
}
void Add(SList* List, SBinary Item) {
    EnsureCapacity(1);

    memcpy(List->Data + List->Count * List->ItemSize, Item, List->ItemSize);
}
void Insert(SList* List, SIndex Index, SBinary Item) {
    SSize Offset = GetIndexOffset(Index, List->Count);

    if (Offset == List->Count)
        Add(List, Item);
    else {
        EnsureCapacity(List, 1);

        SSize Base = Offset * List->ItemSize;

        memcpy(List->Data + Base + List->ItemSize,
               List->Data + Base, (List->Count - Offset) * List->ItemSize);
        memcpy(Item, List->Data + Base, List->ItemSize);
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Почему не имеет. Допустим у меня есть массив структур, и мне надо удалить в середине одну структуру. проще будет ее перезаписать, чем хранить в памяти, кто у меня удален. Вообще было бы проще реализовать список через узел

Comment: @ph4nt0m7 нет. проще использовать 1 `memcpy`, чем создавать новый массив и перезаписывать в него всё остальное

Comment: спасибо. Учту, что есть такая клевая функция